# A select statement using MySQL prepared statements where the SQL statement includes a variable

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections. However, my prepared statement doesn't execute. I think because I get the error message echoed out.

```
$sql = "SELECT user.username, posted, title, context, tags.name AS sport, image FROM post, user, tags WHERE post.user = user.id AND post.tag = tags.id $extra ORDER BY posted $order;";
echo $sql; 
$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $search, $search); 
}
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $posted, $title, $context, $name);

if (!$stmt->errno) {
    // Handle error here
    echo "An error has occured. Please try again.";
};

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
     echo "<article>";
     echo "<h1><span>$title</span><span class=\"tags\">$sport</span></h1>";
     echo "<figure><img src=\"$image\"></figure>";
     echo "<p>$context</p>";
     echo "<p class=\"publisher\">Published $posted by @$username</p>";
     echo "</article>";
}
```

$extra is this code :

```
if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
    $search = "%{$_POST['search']}%";
    $extra ="AND (context LIKE ? OR username LIKE ?)";
}
```

However even if there's no search, an error message still appears. Am I doing the prepared statements wrong?

**UPDATE:**

It seems like it's able to fetch out the right number of rows, however I can't seem to get the result out.

Comment: `mysqli_error($conn)` said what?

Comment: `AND post.tag = tags.id $extra` should be something like `AND post.tag = tags.id OR something = $extra` and you don't have any placeholders in the query to replace with `$search`.

Comment: Remove `if (!$stmt->errno)`

Comment: Your query does not contain the SQL text you think it does.  For one thing, it appears to have no placeholders.  Start by printing the actual content of the SQL string so you can see what it really looks like.

Comment: Consider instead: `AND post.tag = tags.id AND (context like ? OR username LIKE ?)` in your SQL and just feed in `%` when there are no search terms. This allows you to bind parameters and keep from sql injection and your query will run with or without a search term. As another option, consider crafting two different SQL strings and parameters depending on weather a search parameter is filled or not. This might end up being the most easily maintainable solution in the end.

Comment: @markrobinson `$extra ="AND (context LIKE ? OR username LIKE ?)";` There are placeholders

Comment: So I tried what @JNevill said and it still doesn't work. It somehow prints out the tags but can't find the result variables?